# Google Maps Marker Not Appearing

Tags: javascript

I was trying to center the map at the calculated geographic center and then add markers to show the original points, as well as one for the center but they don't seem to be showing up. When I submit the data to getdata.php it just shows a blank screen. Does anyone see a problem with the javascript for the marker? Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check value of `location[i]`?

Comment: You have to show the result HTML code

Comment: Check your `console` what error did you get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check value of `location[i]`? If you are in default `[latitude, longitude]`, try:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[i])
```

EDITED Try this again:

```
for(var i = 0; i<(<?php echo json_encode($counter); ?>;); i++ ){
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitudesoflocation[i], longitudesoflocation[i]),
        map: map,
        title: ("Point " + String.fromCharCode(94 + i))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitudesoflocation[i],longitudesoflocation[i]);,
//______________________________________________________________________________^
```

remove the semicolon

Comment: I still get a blank page when I load it up. Is there anything wrong with my format?

Comment: I'm not a prophet so I didn't know what you upload(your code didn't contain any related code)

Comment: maybe you have to use parseFloat() round input values. It is not clear if those values are strings or numbers.